# Green's Theorem: evaluate the following

Tags: calculus

Evaluate

$\vec{F} = (2xy + x^3, x - x^-1)$

and starts at (2,0), follows $r=cos \theta + 1$ until (0,0) and to (2,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate this integral by using polar coordinates:

$$dA=dx dy=rdrd\theta$$

$$y=r \sin\theta$$

$$\int \int_D 2y dA=2\int\int_D r^2 \sin\theta dr d\theta=2\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta d\theta\int_0^{1+cos\theta}r^2dr=$$

$$=2\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(1+\cos\theta)^3}{3}\sin\theta d\theta$$

The rest should be fairly straightforward...

EDIT: The result is zero, which is expected and can be explained with no calculation at all. Cardiod is symmetric with respect to $x$-axis, so for each elementary area $dA$ with positive $y$ there is an area $dA$ with negative $y$ with same absolute value. Area integral is just a sum of $ydA$ parts and they come in pairs with opposite signs. So the result must be zero, you don't need any advanced math at all :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. In that case the result won't be zero.

Comment: A simple upvote won't hurt either ;)

Comment: Yes. I did. Just substitute $\cos \theta$ with $t$.

Comment: Great. Thank you, again! :)